# Changing the root window of embedded Vlc instance in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, embed, vlc

I want to be able to switch a VLC Instance between frames. The purpose is to toggle fullscreen mode. In fullscreen mode, the Instance should be embedded into a toplevel, otherwise it should be embedded into root.

I have code that does this, but it stops te video when switching between full screen and non-full screen. This would interrupt the playing. So I'm wondering if there's ways to do it without interrupting this playing, i.e. without the player.stop() command.

Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import (
    Tk, Menu, Frame, Label, Button, Scale, Toplevel,
    BOTH, Entry, DISABLED, END, HORIZONTAL, VERTICAL
)
from vlc import Instance


class Test:

    def __init__(self):
        self.Instance = Instance()
        self.player = self.Instance.media_player_new()
        
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry("800x800")
        self.frame = Frame(self.root, width=700, height=600)
        self.frame.pack()
        Button(
            self.root, text="OK",
            command=self.play).pack(side='left')
        Button(
            self.root, text="FS",
            command=self.FS).pack(side='left')
        self.display = Frame(self.frame, bd=5)
        self.display.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def play(self):
        Media = self.Instance.media_new('test.webm')
        self.player.stop()
        self.player.set_xwindow(self.display.winfo_id())
        self.player.set_media(Media)
        self.player.play()

    def FS(self):
        self.top = Toplevel(self.root)
        self.top.geometry("200x200")
        self.player.stop()
        Media = self.Instance.media_new('test.webm')
        self.player.set_xwindow(self.top.winfo_id())
        self.player.play()
        self.player.set_media(Media)
        self.player.play()
        self.top.attributes("-fullscreen", True)

def main():
    Test()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You have to stop it but `Media` has a `start-time` parameter, which might lessen the blow, when restarting in the new window `Media.add_option('start-time='+str(stime))`. Query the time in the current instance then pass it to the new instance. It won't be seamless but it should be close.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I found another solution to my problem, which I will add here (I forgot that I had posted the question) which is just to change the tkinter window, removing unnecesary widgets and making the tkinter window fullscreen.\n This start_time attribute is interesting, though I read that this does not work for URL's, only for files.